# How to convert 4 digit year to 2 digit for credit card expiry input

Tags: jquery, html

I have a input field where I need to input year value return 2 digit instead of four digit

Example : from: 02 / 2019

Need output like: 02 / 19

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="nmipay-card-expiry" class="input-text" type="text" maxlength="7" autocomplete="off" placeholder="MM / YY" name="nmipay-card-expiry" />
```

[Fiddle here:](http://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/2v31w6sk/2/)  after input 2 digit auto add a `/` and `space` before after `/`

Comment: You can use jQuery plugin. https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: problem with auto fill it sometime get 4 digit instead of 2

Comment: var date = "02/2019";
 var datearray = date.split("/");      
 var newdate = datearray[0] + ' / ' + datearray[1].substr(2);
 console.log(newdate);

Answer (score 0):

You can use **substr** function to get last 2 digit if your inputted

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

  function GetLast2Digit(){
  
  var year= $("#txtyear").val();
  var LastTwoDigitOfyear = ('' + year).substr(5);
  console.log(LastTwoDigitOfyear); 
  alert("Last 2 digits are "+LastTwoDigitOfyear)
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
Enter year
<input type="text" id="txtyear" placeholder="MM / YY"/>
<button type="button" onclick="GetLast2Digit()">Click</button>
<lable id="lblyear" />
</body>
</html>
```